# Retrofit Can't return Data

Tags: android, retrofit

i'm probebly doing something wrong, 
i'm trying to figure out how to use retrofit, so for now i'm calling back just a general ResponseBody, and not yet parsing anything, (just a simple http get)

but retrofit can't get the data, what am i doing wrong ? >

my Retrofit API >

```
public interface retrofitApi {

    String baseUrl = "http://localhost:3003/";

    @GET("api/radBox/getDegrees")
    Call<ResponseBody> getCallData();


    class Factory {
        private static retrofitApi service;

        public static retrofitApi getInstance() {
            if (service == null) {
                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();

                service = retrofit.create(retrofitApi.class);
                return service;
            } else {
                return service;
            }

        }
    }


    }
```

and in my main Activity i put >

```
retrofitApi.Factory.getInstance().getCallData().enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            Log.d("myLogs", "log: " + response);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("myLogs", "failed to Retrive Data");


}
        });
```

Comment: do you have the internet permission in the manifest

Comment: yes offcourse ><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: What is the version of your Retrofit?

Comment: Retrofit 2 > compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is caused by using "localhost". Looks like you are using your phone to connect to phone's 3003 port. Exchange the localhost to your Server IP to give a try.

I copy all your code in my retrofit project, I exchange the URL, everything is working well on my side, meaning your retrofit code has no problem.

Comment: thnx ! changed it to an outside server and it worked .!

Answer (score 0):

Try use instead ResponseBody your model (for me it WeatherModel) which must will return from server.
Like this

```
String baseUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/";

@GET("data/2.5/weather")
Call<WeatherModel> getCallData(@Query("q") String q, @Query("lang") String lang,
                               @Query("appid") String appid);
```

and put in MainActivity like this

```
retrofitApi.Factory.getInstance()
            .getCallData("Taganrog,ru", "ru", "bde41abf61e82b6209a544a5ea2ddb76")
            .enqueue(new Callback<WeatherModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<WeatherModel> call, Response<WeatherModel> response) {
            Log.d("myLogs", "log: " + response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<WeatherModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("myLogs", "log: " + "failed to Retrive Data");
        }
    });
```

It's works fine for me